# Changing Text and Hiding a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use a div as a "link" in a way that when the div is clicked it toggles a table's visibility and the div's text changes.
I can get the table to toggle upon click, but i can't get the text in the div to change based upon that table's visibility.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.details td').hide();
  $('#link').click(function () {
    $('.details td').toggle();
    if (('.details td').is(':hidden')) {
      $('#link').text('Click For More Detail');
    } else {
      $('#link').text('Click To Hide Details');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link" style="Color: blue">Click For More Detail</div>
<div class="details">
  <table class="details">
    <tr>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>more details</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing a `$` here,

```
 if (('.details td').is(':hidden')) {
 ////^
```

You could have fixed it by seeing the console itself. Anyway here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2o4La7sy/1/).

Also you can optimize your code like below,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var details = $('.details td').hide();
    $('#link').click(function () {
        details.toggle();
        $(this).text($('.details td').is(':hidden') ? 'Click For More Detail' : 'Click To Hide Details');
    });
});
```